# How to split big 30GB bz2 file into multiple small bz2 files and add a header to each

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, data-processing, bz2

I have large number of `bz2` formatted files (`30GB` each) without any header. I can split them easily in `500M` in each size with the following `pileline`.

```
bzcat logging.abc_gps.bz2 | pv | split -b 500M -d -a 4 --filter='bzip > $FILE.csv.bz2' - splitted_file-
```

But I cannot add the header `['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'timestamp']` that I want to include each of the splitted `bz2` file.

More importantly I want to split the file not based on the `500M`, rather I want to split the `bz2` file per day (example: `splitted_file_2021-01-01.csv.bz2` and `splitted_file_2021-01-02.csv.bz2`)based on the content of `timestamp` in the data.

Data is tab-delimited text, like below (no header, need to add them):

```
19252547212 1   3041    2   1   74.18   1.8504  2021-05-01 00:00:00
19252547213 1   5055    2   1   0       0       2021-05-01 00:00:00
19252547214 1   5073    1   1   53.81   0.1836  2021-05-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: What is the uncompressed format?

Comment: this is the format to uncompressed the data 'bzcat logging.abc_gps.bz2'

Comment: You can use `bz2.open` to open the original file and read line by line. As the date changes, create new output files for the write.

Comment: Hi @ tdelaney could you please add your answer. I am new in this stuffs. thank you in advance!

Comment: Is that tab delimited?

Comment: yes, its tab delimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bz2` package to open BZ2 encoded files and treat them as regular file objects. There is a minor performance advantage to read / write in binary. Assuming your data is either ASCII or UTF-8 and no tab characters need to be escaped in the data, you can just read the file line by line, opening and writing the outputs as new timestamps appear.

```
import bz2
import os

outfile = None
date = b""

with bz2.open("file") as fileobj:
    for line in filobj:
        # get date from, ex. "2021-05-01 00:00:00", timestamp
        new_date = line.split(b"\t")[7].split(b" ")[0]
        # roll to new file as needed, appending, so existing data not overwritten
        if new_date != date:
            date = new_date
            new_file = f"splitted_file_{new_date}.csv.bz2"
            exists = os.path.exists(new_file)
            outfile = bz2.open(new_file, "ab")
            if not exists:
                outfile.write(b"\t".join([b'a', b'b', b'c', b'd', b'e', b'f', b'timestamp']) + b"\n")
        # write the row
        outfile.writeline(line)
if outfile:
    outfile.close()
```

You may be able to speed this up with a pipeline. Give both the decryption and encryption to separate bzip2 processes that will run in parallel on different cores. Instead of a shell pipeline, you can create pipes and files to do it in the script itself. Assuming `bzip2` exists on your system you could do the following. I added the `tqdm` module to print progress along the way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess as subp
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import tqdm

# TODO: Better command line
try:
    in_file_name = Path(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    print("usage: unbzcsv.py filename")
    exit(1)

# build the format string used for generating output file names
out_file_name_fmt = "{}-{{}}.{}".format(*in_file_name.name.split(".", maxsplit=1))
out_file = None
date = b""
bzwriter = None
bzfile = None

# run bzip2 to decompress to stdout
bzreader = subp.Popen(["bzip2", "--decompress", "--stdout", in_file_name], 
        stdin=subp.DEVNULL, stdout=subp.PIPE)

# use tqdm to display progress as line count
progress = tqdm.tqdm(bzreader.stdout, desc="Lines", unit=" lines", unit_scale=True)

# read lines and fan out to files
try:
    for line in progress:
        # get date from, ex. "2021-05-01 00:00:00", timestamp
        new_date = line.split(b"\t")[7].split(b" ")[0]
        # roll to new file as needed, appending, so existing data not overwritten
        if new_date != date:
            date = new_date
            out_file_name = out_file_name_fmt.format(date.decode("utf-8"))
            if bzwriter is not None:
                bzwriter.stdin.close()
                bzwriter.wait()
                bzwriter = None
                bzfile.close()
            print("\nwriting", out_file_name)
            progress.refresh()
            bzfile = open(out_file_name, "wb")
            bzwriter = subp.Popen(["bzip2", "--compress"],
                    stdin=subp.PIPE, stdout=bzfile)
        # write the row
        bzwriter.stdin.write(line)
finally:
    bzreader.terminate() # in case of error
    if bzwriter:
        bzwriter.stdin.close()
        bzwriter.wait()
        bzfile.close()
    bzreader.wait()
```

Comment: Hi @tdelaney, thank you so much! its working well thought the processing time is little bit slower. 

By the way, currently I have to hard code the 'filename'. So is there any way so that I can get the filename from the pipeline like- 

`echo loggin_gps.bz2|run_this_script.py`

In that case what i need to change in your code?
Is there any way to make it bit faster like using shell/bash.

Comment: For a single 6GB bz2 format file turns into 26GB uncompressed file. So reading each of the line and splinting them in a separate file will be some time consuming

Comment: Hi @tdelaney, my existing file name format is  `2021-08-07-logging.abc_gps.bz2 ` and the output format I want is  `logging.abc_gps_2021-05-01.csv.bz2 `,  so what will be the changes for this?
I don't find any header column added in the new code. could you please add that line?
Do I need to replace `# TODO: Better command line` and   `print("usage: unbzcsv.py filename")` with something?

Comment: and when running this script like `python this_script.py filename.bz` then it give me output like below rather then a individual `split` per `date`:
`'2021-08-06-logging-0'$'\n''.abc_gps.bz2
'2021-08-06-logging-1'$'\n''..abc_gps.bz2
'2021-08-06-logging-2'$'\n''..abc_gps.bz2
'2021-08-06-logging-3'$'\n''..abc_gps.bz2
'2021-08-06-logging-4'$'\n''..abc_gps.bz2
'2021-08-06-logging-5'$'\n''..abc_gps.bz2
'2021-08-06-logging-6'$'\n''..abc_gps.bz2`